# Cannot set int? to null inside of ?: Operator

Tags: c#

I can sometimes assign `null` to `int?` but not inside a `? :` , why?

example

```
int? a;  // good
    int? b; // good 

    a = null;  // why is this allowed?
    b = (a != null) ? 1 : null /* and this not allowed? */; 

    b = (a != null) ? 1 : (int?)null /* this is a fix */;
```

Comment: Because both expressions in ?: operator should have the same type or there should be implicit conversion from one to another. That is not the case for int (1) and null.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator):

> Either the type of first_expression and second_expression must be the same, or an implicit conversion must exist from one type to the
>   other.

So, in `b = (a != null) ? 1 : null` type of first argument is `int`, and second argument is `null`, which violates the above rule.

In the second case, `int` can be implicitly converted to `(int?)null`, that's why it works.

Comment: Just to add on, once you cast the `null` to `(int?)null` there now is a implicit conversion that exists.